# Iterate focus components in javascript

Tags: javascript, components

I have some links and want to pass the focus one by one automatically.
I'm using the code below. Works fine passing the focus but only once.
The first time the focus pass, the link change the color, then pass to the next. The one before gets black again and the next is painted red. No problem.
But when its reach the final link doesn't restart.

```
var i = 0;
var letras = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

function pasaLink() {
    if (i == 0) {
        letras[letras.length-1].style.color = "black";
    } else {
        letras[i-1].style.color = "black";
    }
    letras[i].style.color = "red";
    letras[i].focus();
    i++;
    if (i > letras.length) {
        i= 0;
    }
    setTimeout("pasaLink()",2000);
}
```

With the final `if` and `i=0;` I'm trying to get back to the initial index when reach the final element, and then restart to iterate the entire collection of links in `letras`.
This function is called in the body.onload().

Any ideas why its not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `if` to:

```
if (i >= letras.length) {   
   i= 0;     
}
```

**Working example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/Nn62Q/
(click the `Orig` Button to see the behavior of your code and the `New` button to see the behavior of the new one. I have added a `try...catch` to show the error)

**Explanation:**
Let us say there are five `a` tags.
You make `i = 0` when `i > 6` (i.e., `6`). But when `i` becomes `5`, `letras[i].style.color = "red";` at the beginning of the function fails and an exception is throws a exception.   The flow stops here so the `if (i > letras.length)` will never be reached.

Comment: Very silly error, and more silly me that didn't notice it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your condition be

```
if (i == letras.length) {
    i= 0;
}
```

instead?

Once `i` is equal to the length of your array, reset.

Comment: There's the problem. Since it's trying to operate on an element that doesn't exist (accessing properties of a non-existent element) the Javascript crashes at that point and it never reschedules itself after that.